# c# delegate not working as it should?

Tags: c#, delegates

im kinda new to c#, so I came up with this problem. Question: why is func2 called?
oh, and one more thing. say I add a function to a delegate. In this function I call another delegate, however I want to make sure that every other function added to the first delegate is called before this function calls this delegate, is there any clean solution ( not really interested in getInvocationList). 
Thanks guys, you're the best.

```
class Program
{
    delegate void voidEvent();
    voidEvent test;

    private void func1()
    {
        Console.Write("func1");
        test -= func2;
    }

    private void func2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("func2");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.test += p.func1;
        p.test += p.func2;
        p.test();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Every time you change a delegate (+= or -=), you're effectively creating an entire copy of the invocation list (the methods that will get called).

Because of that, when you call `p.test();`, you're going to invoke every delegate in the invocation list *at that point in time*.  Changing this inside of one of those handlers will change it for the next call, but won't change the currently executing call.

Comment: +1. Yes. This is why you can write `var func = p.test; if (func != null) { func(); }` in multithreading scenarios without locking anything. Because `func` is a copy of `p.test` and does not care of changes made to `p.test`.

Comment: but after I call test-= func2  and call getinvocationlist i can see func2 is no more in the list. So you're saying every delegate has two lists, one that is currently being invoked ( and is not reachable ) and one that will be invoked next time?

Comment: @user1316459, it doesn't really have two lists. But when you invoke a delegate from a filed, you effectively say something like: “take the value of the field *right now* and then invoke that”. That means you're invoking a copy of the value of `test`, not `test` itself.

Answer (score 7):

Reed is of course correct. Here's another way to think about it.

```
class Number
{
    public static Number test;
    private int x;
    public Number(int x) { this.x = x; }
    public Number AddOne() 
    {
        return new Number(x + 1);
    }
    public void DoIt()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        test = test.AddOne();
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        test = new Number(1);
        test.DoIt(); 
    }
}
```

Should that print 1, 1, or 1, 2?  Why?

It should print 1, 1. When you say

```
test.DoIt();
```

that does not mean

```
        Console.WriteLine(test.x);
        test = test.AddOne();
        Console.WriteLine(test.x);
```

! Rather, that means

```
Number temporary = test;
Console.WriteLine(temporary.x);
test = test.AddOne();
Console.WriteLine(temporary.x);
```

Changing the value of `test` **does not change the value of `this`** in DoIt.

You're doing exactly the same thing. Changing the value of `test` does not change the list of functions that you are invoking; you asked for a particular list of functions to be invoked and *that list is going to be invoked*. You don't get to change it halfway through, any more than you get to change the meaning of `this` halfway through a method call.

Comment: You appear to be missing the field `x` in your definition of `Number`.